# Titration of weak acid and strong base at low concentrations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, titration

Titration continues until one of the reactants (the one in conical flask) turns out to be a limiting agent as far as I know. From the titration of a weak acid and a strong base, I could learn that the end point is above $\mathrm{pH \ 7}$ since weak acids do not ionize completely. Till this point I could understand everything. But I had a confusion at the condition of ions at end point. In this titration, we are basically dealing with $\ce{H+}$ ions dissociated from water (which is very low) and acid. Usually acids remain a bit more concentrated and release more ions than water does. That is at end point we often ignore the auto ionization of water.

But what if we are dealing with such acid whose concentration leads to total amount of dissociated $\ce{H+}$ ions comparable to $\pu{1 \times 10^{-7} M}$. Will titration be an appropriate way to determine the concentration of acid in this case? Or we need to use some other ways to measure the concentration?

Please let me know if there is any point I'm missing out regarding this topic. And this is my first question in this forum so I'm looking for cooperation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your intuition about there being a problem when concentrations are very low is correct: see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133874/79678) for titration curves as a function of concentrations involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ed V.  Your answer to that question was amazing.

Comment: Yeah it did answer but one thing is missing. That is what will be the alternative procedure to measure the concentration?

Comment: Non-aqueous titrations are one possibility: you need a solvent system where there is less auto-ionization of the solvent.