# Titration of a weak acid with a strong base

Tags: equilibrium, titration

I recently learned that when titrating a strong base like NaOH into a weak acid, like Acetic Acid, a buffer region/zone develops and can be illustrated as follows:

CH₃COOH + OH⁻→ CH₃COO⁻ + H₂O

I've also been told that the hydroxide anions from the titrant will almost solely consume hydronium produced from partially dissociated acetic acid (reaction below)

CH₃COOH + H₂O → CH₃COO⁻ + H₃O⁺

But if a buffer system does in fact develop, that would mean that at least a portion of the acetic acid is consumed by the hydroxide anions.

My question is can someone explain sequentially what happens? Does the hydroxide consume all of the weak acid first to overwhelm the buffer and then consume hydronium?

Comment: See right here for the battle between acetic acid and sodium hydroxide: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133874/79678.

Comment: Reaction of strong/weak acids with strong/weak bases is an evergreen topic and you can find plenty of related info on this site ( See related ) and generally on internet.